# How to get all the observed Elements as we scroll down using the intersection Observer?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

Ok, so i am getting Only 6 divs as i load my webpage, and when i scroll down, the other 6 get loaded (Lazy load), but my Observer does not catch it whatsoever, What could be the Problem here ?

I have tried the Intersection Observer and load them at the end when all the body Is loaded.

**My JS Code Using Intersection Observer:**

```
var targets = [...document.getElementsByName('item-id')];


const options = { };

let clickedId_test;

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries,
    observer){
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
                return;
            }
            clickedId_test = entry.target
            console.log(clickedId_test)

        });
    }, options);


targets.forEach(like_button => {
    observer.observe(like_button);
})
```

**My Images**

[Getting 1st 6 ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqs75.png)

[Even after scrolling only get 1st 6 ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDfnk.png)

Answer (score 0):

When are you attaching the Intersection Observors watchers on the target elements?
Is it being called on the initial load or after all the divs have been lazily loaded?

If it is being called initially, the reason it isn't working could be that at the time of the initial load, only the first 6 divs get captured in the `target` array, and you only keep a watch on those initial divs.
The ones which are lazily loaded are never queried, and hence there are no watchers on them.

If is it getting invoked after the loading of all the divs, including the lazily loaded ones, it should work